# Need to update the elastic search doc without id field with nodejs client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have docs in elastic search having no id field in them, I have some other field _id as a unique identifier.

I want to update the doc by _id field via nodejs client, but it is throwing an error **Missing required parameter: id**

One solution can be, to reindex the whole doc.

Any other suggestions are welcome

I am using following query

```
  await esClient.updateByQuery({
   index: 'storyv2',
   refresh: true,
   body: {
     script: {
     lang: 'painless',
     source: 'ctx._source.like = 100',
   },
   query: {
    match: {
      _id: storyId,
    },
  },
},
});
```

Elastic version: 2.2

Elastic nodejs client version: 7.10.0

Answer (score 3):

You can also [update your documents by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html):

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": " ...do something to your document... ",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "unique-id-field": "the-doc-id-to-update"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
  await esClient.updateByQuery({
   index: 'storyv2',
   type: '_doc',                    <--- add this
   refresh: true,
   body: {
     script: {
       lang: 'painless',
       source: 'ctx._source.like = 100',
     },
     query: {
       match: {
        _id: storyId,
       },
     },
   },
  });
```

Comment: I have tried that, it was giving me invalid_type_name_exception error

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact query and/or node.js code you were executing?

Comment: For now, I have reindex the doc, will try this and let you know. Thanks